# How do I map multiple tables to single entity, with an outer join, in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, outer-join

I have two tables:

**Invoice** (ID, InternalPrice, ExternalPrice)
**InvoiceSummary** (InvoiceID, Variance )

In this application we have a process that goes through the Invoice table, creating object representations in Entity Framework. The application must then compute the difference between the (InternalPrice – ExternalPrice) and store it in the Variance column.

To allow entity framework to perform this efficiently on large numbers of rows (~ 5 million) I have separated the compute result into an individual table. This allows me to use object representations to compute the variance (plus other business logic), and then use 'SQL bulk insert' to insert the data into my database quickly (much faster than a normal Entity update).

I’d like to merge the Invoice & InvoiceSummary tables into a single entity object, while keeping separate tables for the BCP connivance as described above. However there may not always be a matching row in InvoiceSummary.

It looks like Entity Framework requires a 1 to 1 mapping between the two tables to implement a merged entity. **Does anyone know how I can get Entity Framework to represent this with a 0 to 1 mapping?**

If I don’t find an entity framework solution I could use a view to ‘hide’ the underlying table structure. I'm using SQL server, which supports updatable views, so this should be transparent to EF? Alternate structures solutions are welcome as well.

Comment: I have tried to use a view to create the entity structure that I'm looking for.  While SQL server supports updatable views, it appears that EF creates a read only entity object. Unfortunately this does not quite fit my requirements, as I need update access. 

I’m aware that I can manually change the EDML to allow updates to be applied to the view, however these manual edits need to be re-applied every time the model is updated from the database.  This seems like a step backwards - unless there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are correct in your conclusion that entity splitting (split a single entity across multiple tables) requires a 1:1 relationship between the tables. If you have the ability to add a view to the database, I think you are best going that route and then mapping that view to a single entity. There's a big caveat with this proposed solution. Unless you can create an updatable view in the database, you will get a read-only view and you can only map to read-only views using EDMX (the designer). Code First does not support mapping to read-only views.

There are a few other options:

- If you don't need to query the results, you could create stored
  procedure in teh database. That can be mapped to a function in EDMX
  or executed via a function in code first.
- If you do need to query the results and you are using EDMX, I still
  think map an entity to a view is the way to go.
- If you are using code first and you do need to query the results, but
  read-only is okay, you can use dbcontext.database.executecommand.

hth (and hope I've got that all correct since it was from memory...which I don't trust...which is why I write this stuff down in books!)

Comment: Thanks for the response Julie. I'm using SQL Server 2005, so updateable views are supported.

I do need to store the output of the variance calculation, as in many situations this calculation is not quite as 'cheep' as I have made out above! But the function mapping is a good idea, and I might use that elsewhere in my code. 

I'm not actually using code first here - but I guess either could work. 

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I'm interested in how you are combining EF and SQLBulkInsert in your app. I'm guessing that they are completely unrelated operations but if not, yes very interested! (I have a few ideas but...) Feel free to pint me offline since that's totally off topic from this post. [http://thedatafarm.com/blog/contact/]

Comment: I'm trying to keep the two closely linked. I'll ping you other the details. I'm currently working through a proof of concept.